# Unknown variable 'slow_query_log=1'

Tags: linux, mysql, mariadb, webmin

I'm using 10.4.10-MariaDB with Webmin. i'm getting the error "/usr/bin/mysql: unknown variable 'slow_query_log=1'"

I added the below in my.cnf and the error occured

```
slow_query_log = 1
long_query_time = 3
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mariadb/slow-query.log
```

Comment: In what section did you add it?

Comment: @MichaelHampton You mean section in my.cnf like [client-server]? I didn't know there are sections in my.cnf

Comment: Yes, everything must be in one section or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Michael Hampton](https://serverfault.com/users/126632/michael-hampton) pointed out, you almost certainly have slow_query_log in the wrong section or the wrong file.  One can have multiple `my.cnf`s, and each `my.cnf` is laid out as an [INI file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file), with each command picking up different section(s); for example, `[client]` is ignored by `mysqld`, but is read by `mysqldump`, and then overridden by any settings supplied in `[mysqldump]`.

For `slow_query_log`, you usually would want that in the `[mysqld]` section of your server-level `my.cnf`.  Including it in your *user* `my.cnf` (i.e., `~/.my.cnf`) will have no effect whatsoever, as the server is what needs to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Gotta put the configs under [mysqld] section in my.cnf file. Like

```
[mysqld]
slow_query_log = 1
long_query_time = 3
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mariadb/slow-query.log
```