# MariaDB: my.cnf settings cause mysql commands to error out

Tags: mysql, mariadb

in my `/etc/my.cnf` file i have, under the `[client-server]` section, the following:

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

when i try to run any `mysql` commands, such as `mysqldunmp` or even `mysql --help`, i get the following error:

```
mysql: unknown variable 'sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

i understand that `mysql` ignores `[client]` settings in `my.cnf` (as per [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1021349/unknown-variable-slow-query-log-1)), but i see nowhere where this is the case for the `[client-server]` settings.  personally, i've never seen this before, but assume the previous admin knew what he was doing since everything, operationally, is running tickety-boo.

at any rate, can someone kindly suggest how to remedy this as it is preventing any terminal-based commands from executing... which apparently includes `cron` scripts...  :P

Answer (score 2):

Options inside the `[client-server]` option group get interpreted by client tools like `mysql` and `mysqldump` as well as the mysql/mariadb server. Since `sql_mode` is a server-only option you should:

- remove the option from the `[client-server]` group
- add the option to the `[mysqld]` group

see also: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/

Comment: ok. excellent. thank you. upon further digging, it appears that `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` is a MariaDB default. do I even need to have this or can I remove it completely?

Comment: maybe it's a holdover from a past setup where they were straight MySQL?

Comment: The MariaDB default in recent versions is `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`.
This setting is actually modifying the default settings.

Comment: so it's negating the other settings by their absence?

Comment: it overwrites the default settings, thereby removing `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER`

Comment: gotcha. thank you for clarifying. much appreciated.